# Is using `eval()` in a self-contained server-side environment for user-provided JavaScript code secure?

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm developing an application that assists developers in designing their REST API tests. As part of this tool, I'm considering adding a feature that allows users to write their own JavaScript code to execute actions like assertions or loading data from external URLs. However, I want to ensure the security of this feature.

Here's how it will work:

- The user-provided code will only run on their own server and will not be executed by external users.
- The code will be used for their own testing purposes and will not affect other users' environments.

Given this setup, I'm wondering if using `eval()` in this self-contained server-side environment poses significant security risks. Since the code will only affect the user's own system and they will not have access to any critical resources, it seems that the impact would be limited.

However, I'd like to hear from the community about potential risks or alternative approaches that I should consider. Are there any best practices or additional security measures I should implement to ensure the safety of using `eval()` in this context? Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean the users of your application will install it on their own servers, and run their own code there? Or would they install it on their development machines? Or something else?

Comment: On design time they will run on browser, but only the designer can run it. Then they can run it on their CI server. In either case the code runs on the owner's environment. No third party users can run it.

Comment: That sounds a bit like a test runner that is integrated in most test frameworks already. What's the advantage for the user to use your tool and provide code to it, instead of just writing unit/integration tests in the way they are accustomed to?

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. The easiest solution would be to use your tool for code generation of tests, which then are ran by the user themselves, with the obvious security implications.

Comment: @Bergi You can take a look at our current product https://reapi.com And we are going to extends our support from openapi docs to testing. For testing the basic idea is to support complex test case design for non-coders, all within a user-friendly GUI-based environment. This means that users without programming experience can easily create and design intricate test cases using intuitive graphical tools.

Comment: @Bergi  My point is that the code consumer himself is the code producer. That doesn't seem attacker to me. User A never got a chance to inject code to User B.

Comment: If the test cases are created using a graphical scripting tool, not javascript, you don't need `eval` - you can interpret your scripting language. Or generate js code from the test cases, which you can `eval` without fear if your code generation produces whitelisted output. But if the test cases are written in JS by programmers, I don't see why they would need your tool.

Comment: Re "*the code consumer himself is the code producer*", that does not appear to be true, as your product is a collaboration platform. Multiple users would be working on the same API, on the same tests, and run them. I guess it is ok to base your security model on trust among the collaborators, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't try to prevent attacks.

Comment: @Bergi I got your question now. The scenario is that there are always corner cases that requires coders to get involved. The GUI might handle 95% of the test cases, but from time to time developers would like to add some custom logic in order to keep all the tests in one place. We will use sandbox to reduce security implication. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Re `interpret your scripting language` this is in our mind too. Though we are not sure what's the rules to detect `DANGER` code. Any enlight? @Bergi

Comment: Sandboxing is fine, though afaict that would only prevent the potentially-malicious code to a) affect the application backend and b) affect the web sessions of the application users. It still would be allowed to c) make potentially dangerous API calls and d) run code just to consume processing power. You can claim in your threat model that these attacks are unlikely, which is likely fine, but to avoid them you'd have to restrict writing custom logic to the server admins (providing plugin modules?) or use permission model where adding custom code is only allowed for specific users.

Comment: Re scripting language, you don't use "rules" to detect "dangerous code". You would ensure that every command provided by the language for use is benign when executed by your interpreter. This leads to a whitelist of commands and no way to break out of the environment ("sandbox", if you will) of the interpreter.

Comment: @Bergi very helpful. We'll delve into our security model again. We may not be able to get it 100% right in the first a few versions but definitely will try to address as much as these security considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take into account how smart the end user is. Let's say the user is inputting JavaScript into a box, then are they smart enough to not copy and paste possibly malicious code from the internet? Or, are you sure that there aren't any other features/vulnerabilities in your application that could let an attacker put text in that box? If your app runs a JavaScript file from the filesystem, then make sure (at least in the scope of your app) that an attacker can't put/modify files into where your app reads.

Running user-provided code is always a slippery slope. In your case, it seems fairly safe to me because their code only affects them, and the user is a developer and probably needs to know enough JavaScript to use the app in the first place, and computer literacy is required. However, in general, you shouldn't give the user the benefit of the doubt; always assume there is an attacker trying to find a way into your application.

Comment: We are actually using this library https://github.com/nyariv/SandboxJS and we think it is good enough in most cases. But users would question any solution that's not 100% safe. Maybe I can add disclaimer before users decide to adopt this feature.

Comment: @PeiSong Properly sandboxing user input handles 99% of attacks. You're right, as long as you use it right and keep it up to date, then it's quite safe enough. Although warning users about unsafe/untrusted scripts is always a good idea.